# Find two alternatives for ereg functions

Tags: php, posix-ere

ereg and eregi functions will be deleted from Php. Please help to find alternatives for  the following ereg functions:

1) To allow IP addresses only for specific ranges:

```
$targetAddr = "60.37..*..*";  
if (!ereg($targetAddr, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
die;
}
```

2) To replace series of points like .......................

```
$message = ereg_replace("[.]{3,}", "... ", $message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$targetAddr = "/^60\.37\..+/"; 
if (!preg_match($targetAddr, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
die;
}

$message = preg_replace("/[.]{3,}/", "... ", $message);
```

Thomas and Anomareh, your answers helped me to find the right solution. Thank you.

Comment: If Thomas helped you find the solution, you should have accepted his answer IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Those regexes will work the same with Perl regex syntax.

However, the first regex should probably be written

```
$targetAddr = "60[.]37[.].*[.].*";
```

if it should do what you say it should. (Alternatively, use backslashes.)